# git tree branch seams to have no effect at all

Tags: bash, git, git-filter-branch

Hello I want to change email domain and capitalize first letters in committers names however it seams not to be working , where is the catch ? Thank you.

```
cmd=$(
GIT_AUTHOR_NAME=$(sed -r 's/\<./\U&/g' <<<"$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME")
GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL=$(sed 's/@[^,]*/@foo.net/' <<<"$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL")
GIT_COMMITTER_NAME=$(sed -r 's/\<./\U&/g' <<<"$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME")
GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL=$(sed 's/@[^,]*/@foo.net/' <<<"$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL")
git commit-tree "$@"

)

git filter-branch --env-filter "$cmd"
```

Comment: Does it output anything at all? Also, the title is misleading.

Comment: it executes itself but it does not have the desired effect

Comment: Can you please give us as much information as possible instead of as little as possible? What *does* it do? What is the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your `--env-filter` doesn't need to call `git commit-tree`.  It only needs to update the environment.

Beyond that, the problem is your shell script syntax.  When you say

```
cmd=$(
GIT_AUTHOR_NAME=$(sed -r 's/\<./\U&/g' <<<"$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME")
GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL=$(sed 's/@[^,]*/@foo.net/' <<<"$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL")
GIT_COMMITTER_NAME=$(sed -r 's/\<./\U&/g' <<<"$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME")
GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL=$(sed 's/@[^,]*/@foo.net/' <<<"$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL")

)
```

That means to immediately run

```
GIT_AUTHOR_NAME=$(sed -r 's/\<./\U&/g' <<<"$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME")
GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL=$(sed 's/@[^,]*/@foo.net/' <<<"$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL")
GIT_COMMITTER_NAME=$(sed -r 's/\<./\U&/g' <<<"$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME")
GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL=$(sed 's/@[^,]*/@foo.net/' <<<"$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL")
```

and set the variable `cmd` to the output of running those commands.

I'm not sure that building the filter script in a variable is what I'd do, but if it's how you want to do it, this will work better

```
cmd='GIT_AUTHOR_NAME=$(sed -r "s/\<./\U&/g" <<<"$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME"); 
    GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL=$(sed "s/@[^,]*/@foo.net/" <<<"$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL"); 
    GIT_COMMITTER_NAME=$(sed -r "s/\<./\U&/g" <<<"$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME"); 
    GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL=$(sed "s/@[^,]*/@foo.net/" <<<"$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL");'

git filter-branch --env-filter "$cmd"
```

Note the changed quotes (`'...'` instead of `$(...)` for the script as a whole; `"` instead of `'` within the script, because there's no reason to jump through hoops to use the `'` there) and the added `;`s

---

*Update* - To clarify for posterity - the syntax I propose above was tested on a windows system running `git bash`.  The script syntax in the original question resembled bash syntax, and bash would be typical for a git environment, so that's what I assumed.

From comments, it seems OP was using something else (I still don't know what) that couldn't handle that syntax; but found that the suggested syntax does also work in zsh.

Comment: it gives me usr/lib/git-core/git-filter-branch: 1: eval: Syntax error: redirection unexpected

Comment: What shell / command prompt are you running this in?  I've tested it multiple times, including just now having copied-and-pasted the code from the answer, and it's working fine in `git bash` on Windows